# Postgresql could not connect to server (Postgresql 12.2, ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I found some other Stack Overflow threads on this, but, after trying a lot of solutions, couldn't fix the problem.
Upon running the command `psql -U postgres`, I got the following error message.

> psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>   Is the server running locally and accepting
>       connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433"

Running the command `pg_lsclusters` gave me this output:

```
12  main    5433 down   <unknown> /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If everything has been correctly installed and setup the following command should work:

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main start
```

Comment: So, I don't know why but there is nothing in /var/lib/postgresql/12/
So, when I run that command I get this output:
"Error: /var/lib/postgresql/12/main is not accessible or does not exist"

Comment: Try to unsintall and reinstall PostgreSQL.

Comment: That didn't change anything. Does the fact that I'm installing postgresql and postgresql-client make a difference?

Comment: No installing the client should not modify /var/lib/postgresql: only the server works on this.

Comment: Hm. Well I couldn't find an actual solution for this other than reinstalling ubuntu. I'm curious if someone figures it out though